# Can't find user when trying to tag them in comment on Visual Studio Online

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

Whenever I'm reviewing a Pull Request there is a certain user I want to tag in a comment, but when I type @Their-Name nothing pops up. The only work-around I've been able to find is I can add that user as a reviewer, then I am able to tag them in the comments. Is there some kind of setting that I can change on that user to have them always show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is by designed. Take a look at below part of **leave comments** in **[Review a pull request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/pull-requests#review-a-pull-request)**:

> Comment inline in the Files tab in your pull request by selecting the
>   comment icon (Comment icon in a pull request). Leave feedback not tied
>   to a specific code change by commenting in the Overview tab.
>
> **Reply directly to the author** or **other reviewers** by using
>   `@username` and reference work items using `#workitemID` in your
>   comments. You can also reference other pull requests using
>   `!pullrequestID`.

This is also make sense. As a workaround, you could configure [automatically include code reviewers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/branch-policies#automatically-include-code-reviewers) in branch Policy. After this setting, these reviewers are automatically added to pull requests that change files along those paths.

So you don't have to manually add that certain user as a reviewer of your pull request and you could directly @he in the comment.

Comment: Besides, a pull request  **author** could @ others which belong to the project area team even though there are not as a reviewer in the comment.

Comment: I'm trying what you described and it's not working, which is the reason I'm googling this. I can only see five members of our 13-person team with I try to @ the person I want to tag.

Comment: Hi @AmbivalentGeek, If you never @ the person before,  it will not appear in the @ list, you may need to manually add their name first. Next time you should be able to @ them directly.

Comment: We figured it out! :) We had to type the user's name and hit Enter, then he showed up. Appreciate your input.